# How to remove resizable lateral bars in single editor view from VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For an unknown reason, VS Code is showing resizable lateral bars everytime in the single editor view (see attached picture).

[image]

I tried changing different settings, searching on different websites, reseting the settings from the JSON file, and reinstalling VS Code. However, I am unable to find how can I remove the lateral bars. Could you help me figure this out?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is that the bar which allows you to resize the text window or is it something else?

Comment: This bar resizes the window laterally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have [centered layout](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_centered-editor-layout) turned on, which would explain the bars. You can turn it off with the command **View: Toggle Centered Layout** (`workbench.action.toggleCenteredLayout`).

That said, I'm not sure what you mean by "single editor view"; maybe you mean the command **View: Single Column Editor Layout** (`workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle`), or, it looks like you're using Jupyter so maybe you mean the setting `jupyter.interactiveWindowMode` set to **single**. My best guess is you're accidentally running **Toggle Centered Layout** instead of **Single Column Editor Layout**.

Comment: P.S. If this doesn't solve the problem, please edit the question to include a full window screenshot and how you're entering "single editor view" exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked. It was indeed the centered view. I am still not sure why it was activated. Maybe I struck some key bindings and activated it. Anyway. Thank you very much.